# В чем уязвимость input() в Python?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Встретился с тем, что рекомендуют использовать raw_input() вместо input(), мол, небезопасно так. Обьясните пожалуйста, в чем заключается уязвимость?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x

Для python 2.x:
Из документации http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input

> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).

Т.е. будет попытка исполнить то, что ввели.