# Вызов input() приводит к NameError: name 'sadasd' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = input('name: ')
print('hello, ', a)
```

Запускаю ввожу строку и выдает ошибку
NameError: name 'sadasd' is not defined

так тоже

```
a = str(input('name: '))
print('hello, ', a)
```

Comment: запускайте python3 а не python2

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В чем уязвимость input() в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/120397/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%83%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-input-%d0%b2-python)

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, вы запускаете этот скрипт в python2. В python3 все работает прекрасно.
Если все же нужен python2, то код должен выглядеть так:

```
a = raw_input('name: ')
print 'hello, ', a
```